# How to handle a UTF-8 string for the printing and the storage into a file simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, utf-8

I have a piece of code that reads files form a specific directory. Then it prints the filenames at the console and - simultaneously - writes them into a logfile. If there is a file with a Unicode character in the file name in the directory, the script stops with an error. I figured out how to print the filename. But I didn't figure out how to write the filename to a logfile.

This is my code (on a Mac, Filesystem is UTF-8):

```
import sys
import os

rootdir = '/Volumes/USB/dir/'
logfile = open('temp.txt', 'a')

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:                                                  
        file = os.path.join(subdir, file)  
        file2 = file.encode('utf-8')
        print(file2)
        logfile.write('Reading file: "'+file+'"\n')
```

In this case the error is

```
b'/Volumes/USB/dir/testa\xcc\x88test.mp4'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/list-files-in-dir.py", line 15, in <module>
    logfile.write('Reading file: "'+file+'"\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 46: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I change the last line to

```
    logfile.write('Reading file: "'+file2+'"\n')
```

then the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/list-files-in-dir.py", line 15, in <module>
    logfile.write('Reading file: "'+file2+'"\n')
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

I'm doing something wrong with the encoding / decoding. But what?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment from @lenz down below I now can write to the logfile.

Then I added a new line to the code

```
size = os.path.getsize(file)
```

and now I get a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/list-files-in-dir.py", line 16, in <module>
    size = os.path.getsize(file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Volumes/USB/dir/testa\xcc\x88test.mp4'
```

It seems that this internal function also has some trouble with UTF-8. I am stuck again.

**EDIT 2**

No solution but I found a workaround for the filesize by adding a try condition.

```
try:
  size = os.path.getsize(file)
except:
  size = 0
```

Comment: Try changing the logfile open line with:

     logfile = open('temp.txt', 'a', 'utf-8')

Comment: @gkivanov The 3rd positional parameter is `buffering`, therefore you need to specify the encoding as a keyword-argument: `logfile = open('temp.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8')`.

Comment: Why are you doing `encode` at all? Both `print` and `write` should handle Unicode transparently in Python 3 (though you may have to fiddle with the output encoding settings if you are on an old or crippled platform like Windows).

Comment: @lenz Thank you. That helped with one error but now I have a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 strings are default Unicode.  Open the file with the encoding you want and don't encode manually.  This will fix your later problem with `os.path.getsize`, since it wants a Unicode string as well.

```
import os

rootdir = '/Volumes/USB/dir/'

# "with" will close the file when its block is exited.
# Specify the encoding when opening the file.
with open('temp.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as logfile:
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:                                                  
            file = os.path.join(subdir, file)  
            print(file)
            logfile.write('Reading file: "'+file+'"\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out that this problem only occurs when running the script from within Visual Studio Code editor with MagicPython Extension. When I run this code from a normal shell everything is working as expected und the UTF-8 handling is done correctly.